# Mocking getInstance of a singleton using PowerMock

Tags: java, unit-testing, mockito, powermock, easymock

I have the following Singleton that returns an instance of a different class. I want to mock the method on that returned instance object. I've been reading on PowerMock mocking features for final classes and singletons but I don't know if my case falls under those or not. I appreciate some suggestion.

```
public final class SomeWrapper {
    private MyActualObject MyActualObject;
    private static final SomeWrapper instance = new SomeWrapper();

    private SomeWrapper() {
        // singleton
    }

    public static SomeWrapper getInstance() {
        return instance;
    }

    public void setMyActualObject(MyActualObject MyActualObject) {
        if(this.MyActualObject == null) {
            this.MyActualObject = MyActualObject;
        } else {
            throw new UnsupportedOperationException("MyActualObject is already set, cannot reset.");
        }
    }

    public MyActualObject getMyActualObject() {
        return MyActualObject;
    }
}
```

So now in my unit test, I wanna mock the following line:

```
when(SomeWrapper.getInstance().getMyActualObject().isActive()).thenReturn(false);
```

Should I mock the SomeWrapper and MyActualObject? Any code sample as guidance?

Comment: You should not use the Java singelton pattern in the first place. (this does not mean that your application should not have singelton objects...)  Make the sigelton class a normal class with a public constructor.

Answer (score 4):

Using these Mockito & PowerMock versions:

```
testImplementation 'org.mockito:mockito-core:2.23.4'
testImplementation 'org.powermock:powermock-module-junit4:2.0.0-beta.5'
testImplementation 'org.powermock:powermock-api-mockito2:2.0.0-beta.5'
```

You are able to mock an android `MainApplication` singleton instance (for example) using `PowerMock.mockStatic()` and the `when()` mechanism, like this:

```
private MainApplication mApplication;

@NonNull
protected MainApplication getApplication() {
    if (mApplication == null) {
        mApplication = PowerMockito.mock(MainApplication.class);

        PowerMockito.mockStatic(MainApplication.class);
        PowerMockito.when(MainApplication.getInstance()).thenReturn(mApplication);
        PowerMockito.when(mApplication.getBaseContext()).thenReturn(mApplication);
        PowerMockito.when(mApplication.getApplicationContext()).thenReturn(mApplication);
    }
    return mApplication;
}
```

Mocking the private constructor could be tricky - you might try the approach suggested in this post, by using a substitute class in the `thenReturn()` call:
[SO - Mocking Private Constructor](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39701993/2329326)

Answer (score 0):

The point here is: you wrote hard-to-test code. And yes, PowerMock can help "fixing" that, but you might prefer to simply rework your production code to make it easier to test.

For example, by adding a package protected constructor like:

```
SomeWrapper(MyActualObject myActualObject) {
  this.MyActualObject = myActualObject;
}
```

This would allow you to create an instance of SomeWrapper class that receives a completely valid MyActualObject instance.

In that sense: you might want to learn how to create production code that is actually [testable](https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLD0011D00849E1B79).

Comment: I'm okay with you but this does not answer the question.

Comment: You should not assume that the author of the original question wrote the code he is asking about, nor should you assume that he has the ability to make changes to it.